# Cannot find <stdio.h> in android studio project

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, stdio

i am trying to run FM radio project in android sudio but it gives me error

(i downloaded this project from this git https://github.com/mikereidis/spirit2_free)

[IMAGE : Android studio + Cannot find stdio.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVttS.png)

here is my gradle file settings

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testFM"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

and here is the local.properties file where NDK path is declared

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Does it build, or is it just the error in the editor?

Comment: yes, the error is in editor after the project build

Answer (score 0):

Try to run File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...